# Incrementing and storing a "private" variable using closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I am fascinated with the concept of storing and reusing a local variable even after the function executes and exits, and that this is achieved by mere architecture of code (scoping).

I am playing around with this and have an exercise where a variable (var e) should be incremented and reused next time. It increments in the end, however, it is not saved and turns back to 10.

```
var sumFunc = function(a,b){
var c = a+b;
var e = 10;
function subFunction(){
     var d = c + e;
     e++;
     return d;           
}
return subFunction();
};

var result = sumFunc(2,3);
console.log(result); //15 
console.log(result); //15 instead of 16
console.log(result); //15 instead of 17
console.log(result); //15 instead of 18
```

What exactly is happening every time this construction is called, can we go step-by-step and follow the flow?

Below are some of my thoughts & assumptions, let me know if those are mistaken:

1. I referenced the function through a variable, to exclude the chances of this variable to be garbaged. I am scared by the garbage collector, I guess this is what they tell naughty programmers about before bedtime.
2. However, the behavior does not seem to change if I instead simply run 
   console.log(sumFunc(2,3));
3. I return subFunction in the end on purpose, as I am in the beginning of the research and want to keep things as simple as I can. I realise that I probably could return an anonymous function instead (return function()) which then would return d, but I avoid this at this point in time. As I see it this code does absolutely the same thing, but I feel that it is more clear to me and I have better control over it.
4. I came across that self-invoking functions might help but I do not want to use one here (let's say this is not part of my design to immediately change the counter).

Comment: Does this helps.. http://jsfiddle.net/wtbajx1q/1/ ?

Comment: By calling `return subFunction();` you're actually *invoking* `subFunction` and only returns its result (which is 15 for the initial `2,3` arguments).

Comment: @ Rakesh_Kumar yes, this works, but here we have an anonymous function which I tried to avoid (see point 3 in my explanation).

Comment: @ haim770  But this also increments `e` as well, right? This variable is not in the scope of `subFunction` but it is able to see it in the scope of parent function. Why does not `e` equal 11 at the time the function is run again?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you are calling return subFunction(); which basically returns a value.So irrespective of number of times you log result it will be same, instead of that you can do this.

```
var sumFunc = function(a,b){
var c = a+b;
var e = 10;
function subFunction(){
     var d = c + e;
     e++;
     return d;           
}
return subFunction;
};

var result = sumFunc(2,3);
console.log(result()); //15 
console.log(result()); //16
console.log(result()); //17
console.log(result()); //18
```

Comment: I feel I need to clarify it here and have a good understanding of what is going on step-by-step. You say "which basically returns a value". So, value of this function is  `d`. BUT this function also increments `e`! Or are you trying to say that I do not actually **run** this function and **do not** increment `e`? This is not correct, as I can see `e` being incremented, so its new value should be kept. It would be helpful if we can go step by step to follow how the JS interprets this structure.. I am really lost here.

Comment: I mean to say, when you return  subFunction() , it is calling the subFunction method and value of d is getting returned finally. SO result variable will have that value of d. If you print again the value would be same constant value, it is not a method which is getting called. And in my answer I am returning a function reference, so result has that function reference which you can call again and again to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

3.*I return subFunction in the end on purpose.*
  You return subFunction result. To return function you only need to return subFunction; without brackets.

After thant, you need to call it, so console.log(result());

Version with function call

```
var sumFunc = function(a,b){
var c = a+b;
var e = 10;
function subFunction(){
     var d = c + e;
     e++;
     return d;           
}
return subFunction();//function call
};

var result = sumFunc(2,3);//call sumFunc and imidiately call subFunction
//result contains 15, not pointer to function
console.log(result); //15 
console.log(result); //15 instead of 16
console.log(result); //15 instead of 17
console.log(result); //15 instead of 18
```

version with function pointer

```
var sumFunc = function(a,b){
var c = a+b;
var e = 10;
function subFunction(){
     var d = c + e;
     e++;
     return d;           
}
return subFunction;//return function pointer
};

var result = sumFunc(2,3);//call sumFunc and return pointer to subFunction
//result contains pointer to function
console.log(result()); //15 call function in result 
console.log(result()); //16
console.log(result()); //17
console.log(result()); //18
```

Comment: Right that made me very confused :/